# How can I get total pdf pages with ImageMagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am running below script. problem is that how can I get how many pages are in pdf.

```
<?php  // read page 1  $im = new imagick( 'test.pdf[1]' );

// convert to jpg  $im->setImageColorspace(255);  $im->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);  $im->setCompressionQuality(60);  $im->setImageFormat('jpeg'); 

//resize  $im->resizeImage(290, 375, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);  

//write image on server  $im->writeImage('thumb1.jpg');  $im->clear(); $im->destroy();  ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method `getnumberimages()` to get number of pages of PDF.

```
$Image = new Imagick($pathdir.'Padrões de Projeto.pdf');
$num_page = $Image->getnumberimages();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Imagick::identifyImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.identifyimage.php).

Answer (score 0):

### My IM version:

> ImageMagick 6.7.2-7 2016-06-16 Q16

The way to get the number of pdf pages:

1. `$im = new imagick( 'test.pdf' );
   $page_count = count($im);`
2. `$im = new imagick( 'test.pdf' );
   $page_count = $im->getNumberImages();`

If you want to write to image at one time,you could do that like this:

```
$im->writeImages("thumb.jpg", false);
```